# map in python, that map multiple objects to each object in list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

how can I create form a list e.g [[1,2],[3,4]] or [(1,2),(3,4)]
the list [1,2,3,4]

list comprehension(or map, filter)doesn't seems to have map object to more than one other object.

like SelectMany in C#'s LINQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you know that it will be exactly 2 levels deep, you can do

```
[j for i in [[1,2],[3,4]] for j in i]
```

where you iterate with `i` over the list, giving `i` successively the values `[1,2]` and `[3,4]`, and with `j` over these sub-lists. Thus this expression results to `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Answer (score 2):

Standard libs are cool:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> list(itertools.chain(*l))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to flatten the list.

```
[y for x in [[1,2],[3,4]] for y in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>l=[1,2,3,4]
>>zip(l[:2:],l[1:][:2:])
[(1, 2), (2, 3)]

>>l=[(1, 2), (2, 3)]
>>sum(l,())
(1, 2, 2, 3)
```

It's not just what you need?